# flaskで簡単なオウム返しプログラムを作りたい

Tags: python, html, python3, flask

flask初心者です。練習として以下のようなプログラムを書きたいと思っています。

> はじめのページで"write me!"と、テキスト入力欄を表示する
>   入力欄にテキストを入力すると、"you said {テキスト}" という文が表示される。

このために、以下のようなプログラムを書いてみました。

```
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def hello():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return """
            write me!
            <form action="/" mathod="POST">
            <input name="text"></input>
            </form>"""
    else:
        try:
            return """
                you said {}
                <form action="/" method="POST">
                <input name="text"></input>
                </form>""".format(request.form["text"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

しかし、実際に動かしてみるとwrite me!とテキスト入力窓は表示されるのですが、そちらにテキストを入力しても、はじめのwrite me!というページから移動しません...。

説明が上手くできず申し訳ありませんが、少しでもアドバイスをいただけましたら大変嬉しく思います。どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typoです。

GET側のフォームにおいて、 `method` が `mathod` になっているため、常にGETで送信されています。修正したら正しく動きました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！質問させていただいて本当によかったです！